# How to show the same library in 2 different sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I need show the same SharePoint library on 2 different sites. The modifications (uploading a document or updating a document) should point to the same library.

Is this possible in SharePoint online?

Comment: By 2 different sites, you mean subsite within the same site collection or separate site collections?

Comment: between subsites and the same site collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think this video walks you through what you're trying to do.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TntwRm78b_4